# ERROR: [062]: stop file exists for stanza test

Tags: postgresql, pgbackrest

I created a stanza named 'test', then i delete it and tried to recreate it with the same name i got an **error
stop file exists for stanza test** even when i try to stop pgbackrest i get a **warn stop file exists for stanza test**

Any help please ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the question, itself. The `Stanza` is not deleted properly.

To delete a stanza:

- Shut down the PostgreSQL cluster associated with the stanza (or use `--force` to override).
- Run the stop command on the repository host.
- Run the stanza-delete command on the repository host.

Commands:

```
=> To stop cluster
sudo pg_ctlcluster 12 demo stop

=> To stop pgBackRest for the stanza    
sudo -u postgres pgbackrest --stanza=demo --log-level-console=info stop

=> To delete the stanza
sudo -u postgres pgbackrest --stanza=demo --log-level-console=info stanza-delete
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, you need to stop [pgBackrest](https://orahow.com/error-062-stop-file-exists-for-stanza-db/) for all the stanza. Only stopping particular stanza can trigger further error like:

"Stop file exists for all the stanza".

In this case simply stop pgbackrest and start it as mentioned below.

```
pgbackrest stop
pgbackrest start
```